# Problem with Facebook OAuth on Google Appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, facebook, oauth

I am using the "Server Side" flow to get a user's permissions to access some information using Python on Google Appengine.

I am able to get the server generated code from Facebook after the user clicks on the "Allow" button.

However when I get the access token, I run into the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/**init**.py",
>   line 515, in **call**
>       handler.get(*groups)   File "/base/data/home/apps/finisherph/1.348502373491720746/controllers.py",
>   line 21, in get
>       data = urllib2.urlopen(access_token_url)
>   File
>   "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py",
>   line 124, in urlopen
>       return _opener.open(url, data)   File
>   "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py",
>   line 387, in open
>       response = meth(req, response)   File
>   "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py",
>   line 498, in http_response
>       'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)   File
>   "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py",
>   line 425, in error
>       return self._call_chain(*args)   File
>   "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py",
>   line 360, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)   File "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py",
>   line 506, in http_error_default
>       raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code,
>   msg, hdrs, fp) HTTPError: HTTP Error
>   400: Bad Request

Here's the code in my controller where the response from facebook goes after user clicks on the "Allow" button. It's still a hack so the code is a little bit dirty. Still trying to make it work.

```
class Register(webapp.RequestHandler):
            def get(self):
                code=self.request.get('code')
                logging.debug("code: "+code)
                accesst_url=["https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"]
                accesst_url.append("client_id=CLIENT_ID&")
                import urllib         
                accesst_url.append(urllib.urlencode
                    ({'redirect_uri':'http://my.website.com/register/facebook/'}))
                accesst_url.append('&')
                accesst_url.append("client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&")
                accesst_url.append("".join(["code=",str(code)]))
                logging.debug(accesst_url)
                access_token_url="".join(accesst_url)
                logging.debug(access_token_url)
                import urllib2
                data = urllib2.urlopen(access_token_url)
                    ...
                    ...
```

The error occurs here:

```
data = urllib2.urlopen(access_token_url)
```

when I copy and paste the access_token_url from my logs, I get the following error:

> {    "error": {
>         "type": "OAuthException",
>         "message": "Error validating verification code."    } }

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you constructing the access_token_url properly? What happens when you request the url outside of GAE?

Comment: I tried doing it on the browser and I get the OAuthException error above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to access the access_token as url, which  is not quite right.

Here is [an example](https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/oauth/facebookoauth.py#L80) which illustrates how OAuth authentication via FB is done over GAE.

- You go to the https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize? with your client_id and redirect_uri
- Upon authorization, it gives a code and you use `code` and `client_secret` to get an `access_token` from https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
- And then you use that access_token to operate as the Facebook user.

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do, however I get the error in my last step ---- when I request the access token using the code, client_secret

Comment: I don't think you are doing the same. You have to get the access_token and send that as data `urllib.urlencode(acess_token="xxx')1 to your request.

Comment: No I am not yet trying to access the graph api. You only send the access token when you access the graph api. My problem is I can't retrieve the access token yet from facebook because I get the oauth error above.

Comment: I'll mark this as the correct answer because you showed me source code on how to do it. It now works. I think my problem was I wasn't encoding my urls. do you always have to encode your urls using urllib.urlencode(..)? Thanks :)

Comment: urlencode quotes the key,value pairs and constructs your request data properly at places where you might miss it manually :). I was about to say the same. Just follow the example and it seems doing right in couple of lines of code. Thank you.

Comment: Offtopic: do you have a twitter account?

Comment: Jeune, yes - phoe6 is my account name.